# How to build a nested form for Poll Voting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to create a form that is for a poll that shows if you have voted or not. Given a poll like so:

**What is the best camera manufacturer?**

1. HP
2. Kodak
3. Cannon

I have the following models:

```
Poll (question)
PollOption (poll_id, title)
PollVote(user_id, poll_id, poll_option_id)
```

My question is how do I output a form with the question/options along with radio buttons to allow voting?

Here's what I have below. I'm stuck on how to build the radio buttons? Thanks

```
<div class="question">
    <%= @poll.title %>
</div>
<div class="choices">
    <% @poll.poll_options.each do |poll_option| %>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="pollRadioBtn">
                <input type="radio" name="option_id" value="" id="">
            </div>
            <div class="pollVotesBar">
                <%= poll_option.title %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Routes:**

```
  resources :polls do
    resources :poll_options do
      resources :poll_votes
    end
  end
```

**jQuery to post a vote:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/polls/<%=@poll.id%>/poll_options/' + $(this).val() + '/poll_votes',
    data: 'poll_vote[poll_id]=' + <%=@poll.id%> + '&poll_vote[poll_option_id]=' + $(this).val()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i would advise you check out this project where they created a poll system it is help full because it helped me to acomplish my own [risealumni](https://github.com/Swati/risealumni)

Comment: if you having issues still then i can help you out

Comment: Thanks just took a look. Sadly that's all rails 2, so I can't take a look as I'm on rails 3. Would you mind showing me what the form view should look like? I can't figure out how to make the radio tags correctly.

Comment: most of it is almost the same. but let me see if i can try typing for you

Comment: '<input type="radio" name="poll_option" value=<%= option.id %>> <%= poll_option.option %></input>' depends on your attributes. this is just my example

Comment: Thanks, please take a look at the updated question. I pasted in my routes file for polls. Does that look right? I'm trying to post a vote to the controller with jQuery but getting the following error" "NoMethodError (undefined method `poll_vote_url' for #<PollVotesController:0x1075c3d68>):"

Comment: Also, just updated with the jQuery I'm trying to use to post a vote. How but it errors. Idea?s

Comment: create a single resources not nested called resources :poll_votes and try again

Comment: just created a simple gist file for you at github for you in case you are having difficulties https://gist.github.com/1047041

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1047041 just copy and past the url on your address bar if it does not work